# Apply SSL Certificate to AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have requested a certificate via AWS Certificate Manager[image: AWS Certificate Manager]

I have an Ubuntu EC2 instance running a Node.Js Server and connected it to the same domain I've requested the certificate for via Route53.

However, when visiting the website, my browser tells me, that its not secure connection.[image: Not secure]

So my question is how to correctly apply my certificate to my EC2 Ubuntu instance.

Comment: You can't apply these certs to EC2 instances directly.  ACM only works with services where the SSL offload infrastructure is controlled/managed by AWS: ELB/ALB (including Elastic Beanstalk), CloudFront, and API Gateway.

Comment: Please check original question. I have added new answer where you can download private key/cert during startup of EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

`deploy it on ACM-integrated AWS resources, such as Elastic Load Balancers, Amazon CloudFront distributions, and APIs on API Gateway`

So to use the certificate you may need to use one of the services. When having own server, the most appropriate solution is using an ALB (application load balancer) in front of your ec2 instance. There you can select the ssl certificate for the external web access

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using Load Balancer and it worked

Comment: @Florian Yes, and it will charge you about 20 usd/mo , even if you just have 1 instance and few visitors. ELB are great for enterprise applications, but beware, they can be expensive for smaller projects.

Comment: @bvdb indeed, when having a single server, maybe Letsencrypt (or other low cost CA) is good enough